# How to use AngularJS on .NET 6?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

Im a C# developer from some year but only on backend, and Im migrating to a new project that uses AngularJS as a front-end framework.

I looked everything I could to make my setup and learn the basics and even implements TS eventually, but all tutorials point to older version of C# and Im confused, I installed the nuget package but doesnt go to project, instead goes to C:\Users\myuser.nuget\packages\angularjs.core\1.8.2\content\Scripts and I don't know how to use it, Im trying to just make things work somehow to present a simple page like that one below to assure its working, but It doesn't work:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
  {{90*90}}
</div>
```

I tried to add to my _layout a custom file of the minified version of angularjs:

```
<script src="~/js/AngularJS.js"></script>
```

But nothing works, anyone could give me a hint how to install and make this work?

Comment: When you say "the nugget package" what are you talking about? Angular and .NET totally separate things. You can use any backend with Angular as a front end. It looks like you're trying to use ASP MVC which is unusual if also using Angular.

Comment: you will no longer be working with .cshtml files.  (those view-related files that are processed on the back-end by ASP.NET)  All that logic now goes to the front-end, which will be angular/typescript files... when angular builds, it'll produce a single index.html file with related .css and .js files.   Your ASP.NET backend will only need to manage incoming requests, DB calls, and responses (which will be mainly Task<JsonResult>)  All that is handled by the ASP.NET controller files (.cs).

Answer (score 0):

.net core has the Single Page Application (SPA) templates for Angular that offer the ability to develop Angular and React apps that are hosted inside a .NET backend server.

At publish time, the files of the Angular app are copied to the wwwroot folder and are served via the static files middleware( backend is webapi project by default)

You could check the document related:

[Overview of Single Page Applications (SPA) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Tutorial: Create an ASP.NET Core app with Angular in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)